# How to add materialize Date picker

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am new to front-end development, I am trying to add a date picker (*Materialize framework*). I spent a lot of time searching the internet for

> "how to add materialize date picker".

But I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-
beta/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
  <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
 integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
 });

 // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
 </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Did you check this site https://materializecss.com/pickers.html ?

Comment: yes , i followed their instruction . but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [documentation instructions](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html):

```js
  // Using with jQuery
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
=<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
</body>
```

## Note

I just suggest you **first** import `jquery` in your HTML and **then** `materiliaze.js` as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme as your base theme, Most of component are there with materialize  touch.
https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

Check the demo they have.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem.

```html
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Change the input type to "date".

Comment: This is 100% not correct. Materialize uses a text input for it's datepicker and in any case, this question is already answered https://materializecss.com/pickers.html